# Returning multiple recipients names in MySQL (messaging system)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm creating a multiple-recipient threaded messaging system similar to the iPhone SMS system (where both inbox and outbox are combined into one display, and only one thread can exist between two users).

Messages are stored using a senderid column (e.g. "11") and a recipients column (e.g. ",13,10,15,20,").  In order to store multiple recipients, I seperate them out with commas and query the field with a "%" + ",$userid," + "#" call.  The problem with this is that it messes up the LEFT JOIN which connects the recipientsid to the users table (which has the name of the users).

**Here's my current query:**

```
$sql = 
  "SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
   WHEN $userid != senderid THEN senderid ELSE recipients END someid,   
   CASE WHEN 13 != senderid THEN senders.username ELSE receivers.username END somename,
   messages.body, 
   messages.time 
   FROM messages 
   LEFT JOIN users AS senders ON messages.senderid = senders.id
   LEFT JOIN users AS receivers ON messages.recipients = receivers.id
   WHERE messages.recipients = '#' + ',$userid,' + '#'
   OR messages.senderid = $userid
   ORDER BY messages.time";
```

**Here's what I'd like to do:**

- If there is only one recipient id in recipients (the content looks like ",id,", then remove the commas surrounding the id to find the sendername (LEFT JOIN users AS receivers ON messages.recipients(WITHOUT COMMAS) = receivers.id.
- If there is more than one recipient id in recipients (the content looks like ",id,id2,id3," etc.), somehow pull all the names which correspond to the IDs and store the result similar to the following: sendername = "Name1, Name2, Name3";.

Anyone have any idea how I would approach this?  A subquery maybe?  I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st. Instead of:

```
WHERE messages.recipients = '#' + ',$userid,' + '#'
```

you can drop the starting and ending commas and use :

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET($userid, messages.recipients) > 0
```

So you could also have this condition for the LEFT JOIN:

```
LEFT JOIN users AS receivers
  ON FIND_IN_SET(receivers.id, messages.recipients) > 0
```

and then group by message and concat the names with `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Something like this:

```
  SELECT senders.name AS senderName
       , messages.body
       , messages.time 
       , GROUP_CONCAT( receivers.name
                       ORDER BY receivers.id
                       SEPARATOR ','
                     )
         AS receiversNames
  FROM messages 
    LEFT JOIN users AS senders
      ON messages.senderid = senders.id
    LEFT JOIN users AS receivers
      ON FIND_IN_SET(receivers.id, messages.recipients) > 0
  GROUP BY messages.id
  ORDER BY messages.time
```

will give you all messages with sender's name and receivers' names concatenated.

I guess that every message has exactly 1 (or zero) senders. If not, and some messages have more than 1 senders, then you'll probably need to edit the `GROUP BY`.

**Warning**: This type of queries may be slow (or even terribly slow) when there will be many rows in the tables. No index can be used on `messages.recipients` and thus slow down the query. So, you better consider now the option of **normalizing** your structure with a `MessageRecipient` intermediate table.

Comment: This looks amazing, thanks so much.  Trying to out and I'll get back to you!

Comment: ypercube, I'm reading up on normalization now but do you mean creating a MessageRecipient table where you essentially "tag" users to messages?

Comment: Yes, so your `messages.recipients` field is replaced by many rows in that table (one for every recipient in a message)

Comment: Is this (minus multiple recipients handling, still trying to figure that out) a better structure?  I normalized my databases. http://pastebin.com/UGdKsx14

Comment: Yes. The `messages_recipients` can have a compound primary key of `(messageid, userid)`

Comment: @ypercube this seems to do the job perfectly, thanks for all the help.  Here's my final code for anyone else looking at this thread in the future http://pastebin.com/RV2KSHxG <- let me know if I can optimize this at all!

Comment: I'm not sure what these checks for `13` are for. I guess some hard coded special value.

Comment: Anyway, have indexes on the foreign keys. And check your queries for performance as the db grows in size. Then, you can deal with any query that appears to be slow. (or artificially put a lot of rows in the tables and check the queries for speed)

Comment: Oh, the 13 is the equivalent of $userid - just been testing it as an actual SQL query.